# Button with icon on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I'm creating an App for Apple Watch which has a menu with two buttons like the Instagram App does. I'm wondering how you can put an Image file **and** text inside one button.

(It's not two separate objects as both image and text grey out when you click it.)

[image: Instagram Screenshot showing buttons with icons and text]

The only thing I can think of is that the icon and text were created as an image file and used as the background image of the button.

Could there be another way?

Comment: Set the content type of the button to Group in the storyboard and add the image view and label to it.

Comment: @dan Yes, that did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Add a group element and in the Layout property choose Overlap
- now all objects in the group are stacked

[image]